# Split div-box background in three horizontal lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have the following css file:

```
#footer
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 2em 5em 1.5em 5em;
    background: #44494D;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-bottom: 5em;
}

#footer .copyright
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 0.60em;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    color: #999;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

And then this div-box:

```
<div id="footer">
blabla
</div>
```

here a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4dnykjof/

I try to get the div-box background splitted horizontal in three different colors. Is this possible? I want to have it so, that every color region has the same height. I tried much, but didn't accomplish anything.

EIDT: I cant use tree div-boxes because I need content in the middle of the div-box, I have the content. But this content has a larger height than 1/3 of the div-box. (see the edited jsfiddle)

Picture of what I want:
[image]

Thank you! I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Why not just have 3 different divs, each with a different background color?

Comment: Because I need to have content in my div-box, which is in the middle, but bigger than 1/3 of the whole height.

Comment: So why not have 3 divs nested in your footer div, with the middle one holding the content?  I guess I'm not really sure what you want, update your question with more info and I can help you more (maybe a simple mockup would help?).

Comment: I'm still not fully understanding what your asking.  I really think you should post a simple drawing of what you want, it would clear this up immediately

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - I'm sure there's a simpler way, but this gives you the output you want - 3 equal height stripes, vertically centered text and text overlapping the stripes:

```css
#footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 99px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #282828;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 64px;
}
#footer p {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#footer .copyright {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.60em;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  color: #999;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
#background {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
#top,
#middle,
#bottom {
  height: 33.3334%;
}
#top {
  background: #ff9f65;
}
#middle {
  background: #b5b5b5;
}
#bottom {
  background: #82c051;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div id="background">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <p>This is my Text here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you line up the three divs and then edit their height so that they are equal to your div with the content? As for different background colors, just use css. Add ids to each div and use them as selectors in the css and use the property 'background-color' and the value being your color or hex color. If this doesn't help, please comment with a rephrase of your question.

Comment: Like I said, i need do have "every color region [having] the same height"

Comment: Yes so use css to make the heights of the other divs the same as the center one with the content...

Answer (score 0):

Whipped up something super basic, should be what you need.  If you want more customization for the center text, wrap it in another DOM element. Most of the changes involved CSS, the updated HTML is below. https://jsfiddle.net/hkbgtazL/

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="white text-content"> Some Content Here </div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

When in doubt, use more divs :D

Comment: I can't see the changes..?